# Google Sheets Chart / Multiline labels in Column Charts

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I need your help on this one. I'm looking to create a chart (without code) to display data by month in column charts, either like this:
[image: Multiline labels]

Or like this:

[image: Multiline labels]

In the figure 1, I read that the volume of 10 is driven by A, B & C.
In the figure 2, I read that the volume of 10 is driven by 4xA, 2xB & 4xC.

I tried to create my chart but the labels are awful on a single line, and I did not find any way to add a newline characters (\n, 
 ...) in my labels serie.

Any idea to do one or the other one without going though apps script?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: to produce the second image, you could use multiple stacked series, all with the same color. then you could add the annotations to each separate series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a label column to your data. See this example,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H5frKDH612ciLKnB0HY7FiB2FNQBobbhFGcvYqxC7f8/edit?usp=sharing

1. Add one label column for each data column
2. Create chart
3. Use stacked non 100%
4. Set range to include all labels
5. Set labels
6. In customize series check labels is on
7. In the downdown for label pick custom rather than value.

ScreenShots - 
[1. Add Label Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inCxE.png) [2. Set Labels on Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrUx0.png) [3. Turn Labels On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5df.png)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I succeeded to make it work (for the second case in my question above). I realized that putting the labels just after the data column ease the chart creation because the associated label is automatically recognized, no need to select the label column. Nevertheless, the chart function in Sheets remains limited; if the labels is long, there is no line break ...